# Vector data - .xml to CAD conversion

Tags: convert, fme-form, xml, cad

I have .xml file which involves geometry data I would like to convert into .dwg/.dgn/.shp file. File is written in Danish and I am not sure if that can be a problem. I am trying to use FME software but I see errors all the time and I lost my hope.

Here is the beginning of file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<KnudeGroup xmlns="http://www.danva.dk/xml/schemas/dandas/20120102">
  <Referencesys>
    <KotesysKode>1</KotesysKode>
    <KoordinatsysKode>9</KoordinatsysKode>
  </Referencesys>
  <Knude Knudenavn="417292">
    <Ejerfordelingsnavn>HOFOR SPILDEVAND KØBENHAVN A/S</Ejerfordelingsnavn>
    <OprindXYJournalnr>9005</OprindXYJournalnr>
    <Driftsansvarlig>HOFOR A/S</Driftsansvarlig>
    <Vejkode>4476</Vejkode>
    <Husnummer>97</Husnummer>
    <BygvNavn>KB417292</BygvNavn>
    <YKoordinat>6179888.07</YKoordinat>
    <VinkelSymbol>91.1</VinkelSymbol>
    <XKoordinat>723557.54</XKoordinat>
    <TypeAfloebKode>3</TypeAfloebKode>
    <TilladTilslutKode>1</TilladTilslutKode>
    <StatusKode>1</StatusKode>
    <Statusdato>2012-04-11T00:00:00</Statusdato>
    <Kortindeks>1408</Kortindeks>
    <KnudeKode>8</KnudeKode>
    <KategoriAfloebKode>1</KategoriAfloebKode>
    <Initialer>DAN</Initialer>
    <DatoOprettet>2007-06-17T12:38:28</DatoOprettet>
    <DatoOpdateret>2017-08-12T16:25:44</DatoOpdateret>
    <DatoEtableret>1969-06-01T00:00:00</DatoEtableret>
    <Bundkote>5.91</Bundkote>
    <Bemaerkning>QA21S4; A12257</Bemaerkning>
    <BemaerkGeometri>Overløb</BemaerkGeometri>
    <DeloplandItems>
      <Delopland Deloplandnr="1">
        <Initialer>AFL</Initialer>
        <DatoOprettet>2011-07-08T13:39:34</DatoOprettet>
        <DatoOpdateret>2001-05-07T00:00:00</DatoOpdateret>
        <Bemaerkninger>417292-1 fra AFREG.AF_1101</Bemaerkninger>
```

Do you know what else can I do? Maybe I forgot about something important.

Comment: can you given more info on the xml file (like coordinates list).

Comment: I convert xml/csv like this https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/28310/tutorial-fme-approach-to-xml.html [VertexCreator is key] https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/vertexcreator.htm

Comment: What sort of FME errors are popping up? I'd like to restore your hope! The encoding tag looks like UTF8 so there shouldn't be an issue with Danish characters. Are these DSFL files and if so are you using the DSFL reader instead of the XML reader?

Comment: Actually I tried to use FME Workbench and VertexCreator, but file is written in Danish and I am not sure which parts are important for me to focus on. I updated my question with longer script.